# File not found error VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a problem that causes my whole project to function incorrect.
Later I found out what was causing it, and I can't fix it.
The problem is my VB.net application cannot find the file, and I'm 100% sure the file is there.
(to be honest I have to open minecraft.jar in \bin\minecraft.jar, relative from the application. But I tried it with a text file and it doesn't work either)

```
    Try
        Shell(Application.StartupPath + "\options.txt")
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString) ' I've got file not found..
        MsgBox(Application.StartupPath + "\options.txt") 'Displays the path to my file, and in Explorer (Windows) it opens the file
    End Try
```

Comment: Do you a) have permissions to open the file and b) have an application associated with the file extension? Both of these will cause the file not to open.

Comment: try debug.print(Application.StartupPath + "\options.txt") and see if you are getting the path you expect. if you are sure the file is there, then logically the path is incorrect. also you may be having an issue where there is no default executable. try: Shell("notepad " & Application.StartupPath & "\options.txt"). Finally vb in-particular has issues concatenating strings with the + sign. Switch it for an & and see if anything changes.

Comment: Yes I have full access to the file(s) in my question

Comment: Notepad does open it, but what I now need to open is \bin\minecraft.jar. I will change my question a bit

Comment: Please don't alter your questions that much everytime. Future visitors will be even more confused now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) expects a path to an executable. It will throw a `FileNotFindException` even if the file is there when it is not an executable.

From the documentation:

> **Exceptions**
>
> FileNotFoundException -   Shell cannot start the named program.

---

If you want windows to decide which programm to use to open your file, use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

```
Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\options.txt")
```

---

**EDIT:**

OK, you totally changed your question, but I'm cool with that:

> "Can't access jarfile C:\users\max korlaar\dropbox\max " And the folder name isn't max.. It is max & alex.

You have a space in your paths, so you have to quote it (put in between two `"`).

```
Dim args As String = "-jar  -natives""{1}"" -lwjgl""{2}"" ...etc..etc..."
```

Otherwise, the java executable will not be able to distinguish between the arguments you pass to it.

Comment: Thank you, that is solved :). But now I have to fix the error with my Process code from java.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you, but you have changed your question again, and for future visitors, the answer does no longer seem to fit the question, *again*. Please don't do this.